# RN: Scroll items continuously, backwards and forwards

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-scrollview

I have an array of limited data,

```
[0, 1, 2, .... 10]
```

But I want to show

```
[ ... 10, 0, 1, ....]
```

allowing the user to scroll continuously left and right.

How can I achieve this using either ScrollView or FlatList?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it is not supported in FlatList as of now.

Maybe this can help you achieve what you're trying to do.

https://github.com/prateek3255/react-native-infinite-looping-scroll

Comment: Thanks. That's what I'm looking for but this package is giving me trouble as it seems to duplicate the keys